# Variable 'TARGET' not defined in './ruby.tmp.pc' on IBM AIX6.1 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aix

I have removed already installed ruby from AIX6.1 server through below commands

```
rm -rf /usr/bin/rake
rm -rf /usr/bin/gem
rm -rf /usr/bin/ruby
rm -rf /usr/bin/irb
```

After removing we try to recompile the ruby version 1.9.3-p327 and we are getting the error

```
Variable 'TARGET' not defined in './ruby.tmp.pc'
```

And we tried with rvm to install ruby still we got the same error.

We again tried with downgrading rubyversion to 1.9.2-p180 and `./configure` did not give any error, but while giving `make` command I am getting socket address error.

Please help to fix the issue.

Thanks,
Shiva

Comment: It seems that someone else has had the same problem on AIX. He provides a long explanation and solution which you could try: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4403951

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have went through already by changing the file as given in that post. But each time we run again the configuration its getting changed. We dont know how to proceed further.

Comment: What about this one? http://syslog.caetano.za.net/2010/04/22/ruby-on-aix/ Perhaps you googled it already?..but looks like someone managed to get 1.9.2-p136 running. I tried searching for 1.9.3 instructions on AIX but so far no luck on that :-/ Socket address error for 1.9.2 seems very strange, perhaps you could post that part of the error log here also..

Comment: Are you using GNU's make?  Ruby is a bit hard to build at the older levels.  I've opened various defects and the newer levels build much easier.  e.g. the last build I did had not problems at all (a month or so back).

Comment: Also, rvm makes life much harder than it needs to be.  There are much better alternatives to rvm.